# Unity. Создание кнопок с помощью скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Работаю с движком Unity, на языке c#. Я не знаю как сделать так, что бы кнопки созданные с помощью скрипта выполняли какой то метод, а именно присваивание определенного значению моему иксу и удаляли сами себя после присваивания. 
Мне нужно будет создать таких кнопок около 100, и они должны нести в себе случайное число, как на гифке( в верхней части гиф кнопки созданы без использования скрипта и работают как нужно, за исключением удаления самой себя, а в нижней части кнопки создаются скриптом, но не работают) Подкиньте статью на эту тему или может даже решение проблемы, если вам не трудно

[визуализация проблемы](https://ibb.co/pWZn9jm).

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;


public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform panel;
    string Number;
    public Font font;
    public Text x;
    int chislo = 0;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        x.text = string.Format("X= {0}", chislo);
    }

    public void createButton()
    {

        Number = Convert.ToString(UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 50));

        GameObject newButton = new GameObject("knopka" + Number, typeof(Image), typeof(Button), typeof(LayoutElement));
        newButton.transform.SetParent(panel);

        newButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0, 1, 0, 1);
        newButton.transform.SetParent(newButton.transform);
        RectTransform rect = newButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rect.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
        rect.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);
        rect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(70, -65);
        rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100, 100);



        GameObject newText = new GameObject("New text" + Number, typeof(Text));
        newText.transform.SetParent(newButton.transform);
        newText.GetComponent<Text>().text = Number;
        newText.GetComponent<Text>().font = font;
        newText.GetComponent<Text>().fontSize = 50;
        RectTransform rt = newText.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rt.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rt.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
        rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, 0);
        newText.GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        newText.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
    }

    public void chislo1()
    {
        chislo = 1;
    }
    public void chislo6()
    {
        chislo = 6;
    }
    public void chislo11()
    {
        chislo = 11;
    }
    public void chislo43()
    {
        chislo = 43;
    }
    public void chislo22()
    {
        chislo = 22;
    }
    public void chislo85()
    {
        chislo = 85;
    }


}
```

Comment: Решено. Путем создания локальной переменной во время создания кнопки.
int Number = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 60);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы кнопка выполняла какое-либо действие по клику, можно использовать метод [Button.OnClick()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html).
Пример из документации:

```
m_YourFirstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
m_YourSecondButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Hello"); });
m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42))
```

В вашем случае, будет удобно сделать метод, который будет принимать числовой параметр и использовать, что-то типа:

```
    myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42))
    public void ButtonClicked (int number) {
        chislo = number; 
    }
```

При этом, вы сможете задавать кнопкам любое случайное число, сразу при их создании.

Comment: Теперь проблема в другом, значения числа всегда одно и тоже, равно последнему случайно сгенерированному 


[https://ibb.co/NgRtF86](https://ibb.co/NgRtF86)

Comment: код с использованием полученной информации я добавил выше

Comment: @VladislavSit мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его, как правильный. Проблема генерации случайного числа не относится к этому вопросу